# Regarding reading Jmeter output in Java

Tags: java, jmeter

I have executed jmeter script through java, however I am not able to get output in java. Could you please help me in that.

Regards
Pankaj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you need to add [Summarizer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-two-techniques-get-jmeter-test-results-non-gui-mode/) to your class, this way you will get normal console output regarding the test progress via [Summarizer](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/reporters/Summariser.html) and will be able to configure the results file location via [ResultCollector](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/reporters/ResultCollector.html).

Example code:

```
Summariser summer = null;
String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
    summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
}

String resultFile = "/path/to/test/result.jtl";
ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
logger.setFilename(resultFile);
testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);
```

Full class just in case:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.Summariser;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;

import java.io.File;

public class ExistingTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("/path/to/your/jmeter/bin/jmeter.properties");
        JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("/path/to/your/jmeter");
        JMeterUtils.initLocale();

        SaveService.loadProperties();

        HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(new File("/path/to/your/jmeter/extras/Test.jmx"));

        Summariser summer = null;
        String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
        if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
            summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
        }

        String resultFile = "/path/to/test/result.jtl";
        ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
        logger.setFilename(resultFile);
        testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);

        jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
        jmeter.run();
    }
}
```